# is react inconsistent when setting values?

Tags: reactjs

Confused as to why the first case works but the second case doesn't:

`this.state{hidden:true}`

case 1:

```
return (
    <div>
      <input type = 'checkbox' id = "boldCheckbox" hidden={this.state.hidden} 
                     checked={this.state.checked} onChange={this.checkbox.bind(this)} />
    </div>
);
```

case 2:

```
return (
    <div>
      <input type = 'checkbox' id = "boldCheckbox" hidden='true' 
                     checked={this.state.checked} onChange={this.checkbox.bind(this)} />
    </div>
);
```

in case 1 the input is hidden but in case 2 it isn't.

Comment: `hidden` expects a `boolean` value, not a `string` value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**String** is not the same as **Boolean**

```
  <input type = 'checkbox' id = "boldCheckbox" hidden={true}
```

Comment: can we use hidden = true ?

Comment: nope, it reacts syntax you need to add the  {} to tell react a "variable" will be inside, otherwise, it will give a syntax error

Comment: I have to wait another 3 minutes!

Comment: You can also write the boolean shorthand `hidden` without the `={true}`